# .bash_profile sed: \1 not defined in the RE

Tags: sed, homebrew, bash

I've to set up a local web development environment on my OS X 10.9 and installed Homebrew. Next step in my guide tells me to add logic to my `~/.bash_profile` with the following command:

```
echo "export PATH=\$(echo \$PATH | sed 's|/usr/local/bin||; s|/usr/local/sbin||; s|::|:|; s|^:||; s|(.*)|/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:\1|')" >> ~/.bash_profile && source ~/.bash_profile
```

When I enter it in the terminal I get:

```
sed: 1: "s|/usr/local/bin||; s|/ ...": \1 not defined in the RE
```

Is it `export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:$PATH` that should be written to my `.bash_profile`? And why do I get that error?

Answer (score 152, accepted):

You should use `\(.*\)` instead of `(.*)`.

`sed` uses Basic Regular Expressions (BRE) by default, which uses `\(` and `\)` for group capturing, not just `(` and `)` as used in Extended Regular Expressions (ERE). Since your expression used `(.*)` instead of `\(.*\)`, it is not recognised as a group capture, and thus nothing is captured for use with `\1`.

Some `sed` implementations, such as the ones provided by GNU and BSD, do have an extension for specifying the use of ERE, but it is [not specified by POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html), and you cannot use it if you want to be portable.

Comment: +1; conversely, use `-E` to enable support for _extended_ regular expressions, where `(` and `)` needn't (mustn't) be escaped - works on both OS X (which the OP is on) and GNU/Linux (where only the alias `-r` is _documented_, however).

Comment: It's not true that "sed uses BREs". What is sadly true is that it uses them *by default*. BREs are ancient and deprecated and any new use of sed should always be with the -E (OSX/BSD) or -r (GNU) flag to use the EREs.

Comment: @ooga Updated the post with corrected information now.

Comment: Thanks! `\(.*\)` doesn't give me an error. But now the whole `echo` is written into my `.bash_profile` 0_0

Comment: I'm guessing that's the intent: to take whatever PATH has been defined in your .bash_profile up to that point, and then rework it if necessary to make absolutely sure that `/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin` appears at the beginning. It specifically takes out any references to those two directories already in the PATH, and then replaces them at the front.

Comment: This tip fixed my sed regex on OSX

Comment: Extended Regular Expressions just looks at you `(.*)` but the Basic Regular Expressions knows your struggles and cheers you on `\(.*\)`

Comment: On OS X 12.3.1 -E does not free the user from needing to escape parens. This contradicts the statement in the "Jul 12, 2014 at 22:00" comment.