# Using sed - how to replace two HTML tags or patterns with unknown content in-between?

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed

I want to leave the unknown content between tags intact, but want to match all tags that use:

```
<div class="section1-title">arbitrary content here</div>
```

and replace the surrounding tags with:

```
<h2>arbitrary content here</h2>
```

I've come up with the following, but obviously it's not working as in the second part it's literally substituting "].*[<]/h2[>]" for each match found.

```
sed -i 's/[<]div class=\"section1-title\"[>].*[<]\/div[>]/<h2[>].*[<]\/h2[>]/g'
```

I'd like to specifically know how to leave that middle content intact, no matter what is in there, and just match those surrounding tags as obviously there are quite a few elements with  so I can't just separately search & replace them. The first part of the sed statement does seem to match the right content as far as I can tell, it's mostly part 2 that I'm unsure of.

Comment: It is always recommended to use correct tools for HTML parsing `sed`, `awk` are not meant for HTML parsing.

Comment: Which tools would you recommend?

Comment: And why is it not recommended to use sed or awk for those purposes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is a backref.

```
    bash-3.2$ sed 's/<div class=\"section1-title\">\(.*\) 
    <\/div>/<h2>\1<\/h2>/g' <<< '<div class="section1-title">arbitrary 
    content here</div>'
    <h2>arbitrary content here</h2>
```

The parentheses around your content - `\(.*\)` - allow it to be referenced later as is with the `\1`.

See: https://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html

and [.bash_profile sed: \1 not defined in the RE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24717676/bash-profile-sed-1-not-defined-in-the-re) for an explanation about why the parentheses should be escaped in your regex.

Comment: Thank you! That is what I was looking for, and a great resource. 

I am discovering the regex is extraordinarily greedy, though, and is gobbling content between the first occurrence of "section1-title" and several other </div>'s later. Looking into it myself, but would you happen to have advice on having it stop at the first match of </div>?

Comment: You probably want to use a `?` to make it a lazy rather than a greedy match- `\(.*?\)` - which will match the fewest characters before the `<\/div>`. Or a negated character class might make more sense - like `\([^<]*\)` - which will match as many non-`<` characters as possible.
(also see https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html )

Comment: The second one I had tried, but there are some tags that contained <span> classes within which I wanted to leave. Using ? is perfect and matches exactly what I need. Thank you very much for your help! Definitely learned a lot for future reference.