# Linux sed command to replace dynamic values

Tags: sed

I'd like to replace several string in a file having a 'false' value with a 'true' value with a single 'sed' command.

My problem is that in the middle of the string there is a dynamic part like one,two,three,[..] that I want to maintain in the replacement.

For example, this is the content of `MyFile.txt`:

```
    payinstr.one.enabled=false
    payinstr.two.enabled=false
    payinstr.three.enabled=false
    [..]
```

I want to obtain:

```
payinstr.one.enabled=true
payinstr.two.enabled=true
payinstr.three.enabled=true
[..]
```

Is there a way using 'sed' command to change these string with a 'true' value considering that there is a dinamic part on it?
Somethings like:

```
sed -i 's/payinstr.*.enabled=false/payinstr.*.enabled=true/'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a capture group with extended regular expressions (`-E` or `-r`):

```
sed -i -E 's/payinstr\.(.+)\.enabled=false/payinstr.\1.enabled=true/'
```

or more concisely,

```
sed -i -E 's/(payinstr\..+\.enabled=)false/\1true/'
```

[Try it online](https://sed.js.org/?snippet=dqLzyp).

Comment: thnaks it works if i leave the -i.  Otherwise it fails per:

Comment: sed -ir 's/payinstr\.(.+)\.enabled=false/payinstr.\1.enabled=true/g' prova.txt 
sed: -e expression #1, char 58: invalid reference \1 on `s' command's RHS

Comment: @Alex My bad, it should be `-ri` or `-i -r`. I forgot that `-i` takes an optional argument.

Comment: `-r` is not portable; some `sed` variants prefer `-E`, and some do not support extended regular expressions.

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
sed -iE 's/\(.*\)=false/\1=true/g' inp.txt
```

with help from: [.bash_profile sed: \1 not defined in the RE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24717676/bash-profile-sed-1-not-defined-in-the-re)

EDIT: LOL `-r` is not in the man-page of the sed I am using ....

Comment: `-iE` passes `E` as the optional argument to `-i` (i.e. make a backup with the suffix `E`). You want `-Ei` or `-i -E`.